# Drawing a single line in different Color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, drawing, lines

I am trying to draw a line which can be broken into different segments (in C# winforms).

Each segment will then be of a different colour and also display a name on it.

What I've done right now is:

```
 int startXPosition = 100;
 int startYPosition = 50;
 int numSegment = 5;
 int endXPosition = startXPosition;
 int endYPosition = this.Height / numSegment;

 Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
 e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, new       Point(startXPosition, startYPosition), new      Point(endXPosition, endYPosition));
```

This will allow me to draw a line base on the form's height / 5 (the number of segment) using black color.

How do I continue from here such that I am able to draw the rest of the segment (4) in which it will be in different colour?

How can i do it in such a way that I won't need to define the colour and the code can auto assign a color to each different segment?

Comment: Split the line into parts and draw with different color

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be easily solved by linear algebra (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra)

You need to represent your start and end in vector form in terms of

> start + (end - start) * n, where n is [0..1]

As you are not using vectors here you will need to split x and y separately

Your start position is `start`, which is equal to n=0, your final position (of the fifth segment) is `end`, which is equivalent of n = 1. Every position in between is a fraction of `n`.

Now you need to draw 5 lines, where we will use the formula above

1. Draw from n = 0 to n = 1/5
2. Draw from n = 1/5 to n = 2/5
3. Draw from n = 2/5 to n = 3/5
4. ..
5. Draw from n = 4/5 to n = 5/5 (=1)

Each with a different color

Answer (score 0):

If segments are connected, then you can represent the whole *figure* as an array of points. First point is connected to second, second to third, etc.

If you need to have `Color`'s, then you can either have it as a separate array, or as a part of *segment* type (which makes more sense to make, the more parameters you need).

According to your requirements, it is enough in your case to define array of `Color`'s and the *line* somehow (possible by using `y=kx+b` expression or by starting/ending point). Then, when drawing, you can split the line in segments (by using geometry formulas) and draw each with its own color.

To example,

```
Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.Red, Color.Black, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Purple};
var k = 1;
var b = 0; // y = x, diagonal line

for(int i = 0; i < colors.Lengh; i++)
{
    // calculate line coords
    var y1 = this.Height / colors.Length * i;
    var x1 = (y1 - b) / k;  // x = (y - b) / k
    var y2 = this.Height / colors.Length * (i + 1);
    var x2 = (y2 - b) / k;

    using(var pen = new Pen(colors[i]))
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, (int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x2, (int)y2);
}
```

Note, this is not accurate, because you have to use `ClientRectangle` reduced by 1 point (and not form `Height`). Otherwise you will draw on *non-client* area (which is not a problem, but you will not see there anything drawn).

It's a trivial task to get `k` and `b` for a given starting/ending point of the line, not going to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

This should do for you, I comments the code best I could, feel free to ask questions about what I did.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            Bitmap buffer;  //used to draw the lines and txt on first then make the Forms     Background image = buffer
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                //set the buffer to the same size as the form
                buffer = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

                //calls the method below
                DrawLines(100,50,5,Graphics.FromImage(buffer));

                //sets the background image to = buffer
            BackgroundImage = buffer; 

        }

        public void DrawLines(int startX, int startY, int segments, Graphics g)
        {
            // this needs to be looked at since it pushes the lines off the screen
            //perhaps you need to indicate a total line length then use it here instead of this.Height

            //int TotalLength=500;
            //int segmentLength = TotalLength / segments; 

            int segmentLength=this.Height/segments; 

            //I have created a array containing 5 Colors, this way I can reference them from within the For Loop below
            //You can use whichever colors you wish

            Color[] Colors = new Color[] { Color.Black, Color.Red,Color.Orange,Color.Yellow,Color.Green };

            //Loop through each of the segments

            for (int y = 0; y < segments; y++)
            {
                //the using statements ensures your new p is disposed of properly when you are finished.  You could also use
                // Pens.Red, or Pens.Black, which do not need to be disposed of instead of creating a new one
                using (Pen p= new Pen(Colors[y]))
                    g.DrawLine(p,new Point(startX,startY+(y*segmentLength)),new Point(startX,startY+((y+1)*segmentLength)));
                //same thing for Pens also applies to Brush...  Brushes.Red, Brushes.Black etc...
                using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Colors[y]))
                    g.DrawString(Colors[y].Name, Font, b, new Point(startX + 5, startY + (y * segmentLength) + (segmentLength / 2)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```